# Crash when run RENDERTHREAD_SKIA_PIPELINE_TEST(SkiaPipeline, renderFrame) testcase

Tags: android

accord to base\libs\hwui\tests\macrobench\how_to_run.txt
I compile hwui_unit_test app, and push to our android device, after reboot we run this testcase, and crash every time,

the result of testcase run process:

```
XXX:/data # ./hwui_unit_tests
Running main() from external/googletest/googletest/src/gtest_main.cc 
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test suite. 
[----------] Global test environment set-up. 
[----------] 1 test from SkiaPipeline 
[ RUN   ] SkiaPipeline.renderFrame_SkiaGL 
Segmentation fault
```

the crash information:

```
2022-02-18 01:18:01.911 25505-25505/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2022-02-18 01:18:01.911 25505-25505/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: XXX cust format error.:user/release-keys'
022-02-18 01:18:01.911 25505-25505/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
2022-02-18 01:18:01.911 25505-25505/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
2022-02-18 01:18:01.912 25505-25505/? A/DEBUG: Timestamp: 2022-02-18 01:18:01+0800
2022-02-18 01:18:01.912 25505-25505/? A/DEBUG: pid: 25461, tid: 25498, name: RenderThread  >>> ./hwui_unit_tests <<<
2022-02-18 01:18:01.912 25505-25505/? A/DEBUG: uid: 0
2022-02-18 01:18:01.912 25505-25505/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xdd0
2022-02-18 01:18:01.912 25505-25505/? A/DEBUG: Cause: null pointer dereference
2022-02-18 01:18:01.912 25505-25505/? A/DEBUG:     x0  0000000000001f02  x1  0000007d8937f190  x2  0000000000000004  x3  0000000000000005
2022-02-18 01:18:01.912 25505-25505/? A/DEBUG:     x4  0000000000000000  x5  4008000000000000  x6  0000000000000000  x7  7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
2022-02-18 01:18:01.912 25505-25505/? A/DEBUG:     x8  0000000000000000  x9  0000000000001f03  x10 0000007e0c0a305c  x11 000000000000003b
2022-02-18 01:18:01.912 25505-25505/? A/DEBUG:     x12 0000000000000018  x13 ffffffffffffffff  x14 ffffffffff000000  x15 ffffffffffffffff
2022-02-18 01:18:01.912 25505-25505/? A/DEBUG:     x16 0000007e0bd20268  x17 0000007e095e2280  x18 0000007d88c26000  x19 0000000000001f02
2022-02-18 01:18:01.912 25505-25505/? A/DEBUG:     x20 0000005b6f26d73c  x21 0000000000000000  x22 0000007e0bd1e9b8  x23 0000007e094e6328
2022-02-18 01:18:01.912 25505-25505/? A/DEBUG:     x24 0000007d89380020  x25 0000007d8937fd50  x26 0000007d89380020  x27 0000007e0c6ae020
2022-02-18 01:18:01.912 25505-25505/? A/DEBUG:     x28 20c49ba5e353f7cf  x29 0000007d8937fa50
2022-02-18 01:18:01.912 25505-25505/? A/DEBUG:     sp  0000007d8937fa00  lr  0000005b6f3e1494  pc  0000007e0bd1e9ec
2022-02-18 01:18:01.981 25505-25505/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2022-02-18 01:18:01.981 25505-25505/? A/DEBUG:       #00 pc 00000000000079ec  /system/lib64/libGLESv1_CM.so (glGetString+52) (BuildId: 2f2949fde778c51cf7d20df6fd749253)
2022-02-18 01:18:01.981 25505-25505/? A/DEBUG:       #01 pc 00000000003133ec  /data/hwui_unit_tests (GrGLCreateNativeInterface()+68) (BuildId: 614b58f18958c093710e2b40bd8c6044)
2022-02-18 01:18:01.981 25505-25505/? A/DEBUG:       #02 pc 00000000004a58f8  /data/hwui_unit_tests (android::uirenderer::debug::GlesDriver::getSkiaInterface()+16) (BuildId: 614b58f18958c093710e2b40bd8c6044)
2022-02-18 01:18:01.981 25505-25505/? A/DEBUG:       #03 pc 00000000002de90c  /data/hwui_unit_tests (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::requireGlContext()+108) (BuildId: 614b58f18958c093710e2b40bd8c6044)
2022-02-18 01:18:01.981 25505-25505/? A/DEBUG:       #04 pc 00000000002fd3f8  /data/hwui_unit_tests (android::uirenderer::TestUtils::TestTask::run()+40) (BuildId: 614b58f18958c093710e2b40bd8c6044)
2022-02-18 01:18:01.981 25505-25505/? A/DEBUG:       #05 pc 00000000003051e8  /data/hwui_unit_tests (std::__1::packaged_task<void ()>::operator()()+88) (BuildId: 614b58f18958c093710e2b40bd8c6044)
2022-02-18 01:18:01.981 25505-25505/? A/DEBUG:       #06 pc 00000000002a9b48  /data/hwui_unit_tests (android::uirenderer::WorkQueue::process()+228) (BuildId: 614b58f18958c093710e2b40bd8c6044)
2022-02-18 01:18:01.981 25505-25505/? A/DEBUG:       #07 pc 00000000002a988c  /data/hwui_unit_tests (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+68) (BuildId: 614b58f18958c093710e2b40bd8c6044)
2022-02-18 01:18:01.981 25505-25505/? A/DEBUG:       #08 pc 00000000000136d4  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+288) (BuildId: 5719b1e0d0dc5d254cb5883c52d4135f)
2022-02-18 01:18:01.981 25505-25505/? A/DEBUG:       #09 pc 00000000000cf7c0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36) (BuildId: e8a9123d826d0dbc18dd7e6056df7051)
2022-02-18 01:18:01.981 25505-25505/? A/DEBUG:       #10 pc 00000000000721a8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: e8a9123d826d0dbc18dd7e6056df7051)
```

I add some logcat information into sk_sp GrGLMakeAssembledInterface(void *ctx, GrGLGetProc get) function，when it run the normal system application, it look run fine, and no problem，so I do not know why the test case get crash, and they run the same GrGLMakeAssembledInterface functions, and input the same params.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: some information:  1、Android Q frameworks aosp source code； 2、I want check hwui render process，so I compile hwui_unit_tests testcase in \frameworks\base\libs\hwui\Android.bp，3、I push hwui_unit_tests into our android devices run Android Q OS， and run the testcase then get the above crash information， so I do not know what reason.

Comment: I want to know : 1、testcase source code has bug or not?  2、test process is right or not, I do it following the document in base\libs\hwui\tests\unit\how_to_run.txt